# Form NSArray using components seperated and form another array using dulicate elements

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have array of element like this

```
"Cosmetics~Sample~test1",
"Cosmetics~Sample~test2",
```

i need to display like this

cosmetics --sample --> test1,test2 (its like cosmetics as main and cosmetics sub will be Sample and Sample sub have test1 and test2 element) like branch

```
 NSArray * seperate=[[NSArray alloc]init];
for (int i =0; i < jsonarray.count; i++) {
    NSString *sam=[[jsonarray valueForKey:@"category"]objectAtIndex:i]; 
    seperate=[sam componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];       
    [cellarray addObject:[seperate objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

I have done separating those with ~ mark but i cant compare those and form like i mentioned.. Help Pls...

Comment: could you please explain better what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can achieve this using array of Dictionaries.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha my entire jsonarray have elements with "~" mark i have to split it using that..where element before 1st "~" mark have to be form in array with no repetive elements and element before "~" mark have to form array with no repetive elements and it goes on like this..for forming no repetive i can use NSSet but i'm not aware that if cosmetics have another element like sample1 ,sample2 i dono hw to form that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Merger` two `array` without duplication maintaing order like this:

```
NSArray *a= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cosmetics",@"Sample",@"test1", nil];
NSArray *b= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cosmetics",@"Sample",@"test2", nil];
NSMutableOrderedSet *setA = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:a];
NSOrderedSet *setB = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:b];
[setA unionOrderedSet:setB];
NSLog(@"Merged One : %@", [[setA array] componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
```